# How can I get undo behavior in Evil similar to Vim's?

Tags: init-file, customize, evil, undo-tree-mode

The default undo behavior in Evil is too coarse-grained because it considers anything taking place between entering insert mode and leaving it as one edit operation.  When you enter a whole paragraph of text during one insert and then execute undo, the whole paragraph is removed.  In contrast to that, Vim starts a new undo unit whenever you move the cursor in insert mode by means other than entering text.

Evil has a customization variable that can be used to get a more fine-grained undo history:

```
(setq evil-want-fine-undo t)
```

With this setting, Evil starts a new undo unit when the cursor is moved in insert mode, just like Vim does.  However, this setting also messes with how the replace operation is handled: if you replace a word using `cw`, you have to undo twice to restore the original word: once for removing the new word and once for reinserting the original word.  This is inconsistent with Vim and doesn't make much sense because replace should be atomic.

The question: How can I configure Evil and undo-tree in order to get Vim's undo behavior?

Comment: File an issue here: https://bitbucket.org/lyro/evil/issues?status=new&status=open (Evil generally considers divergences from vim to be bugs).

Comment: @shosti, you are right but the existence of the customization variable suggests that they decided to make an exception to that rule in the present case.  I'll file a bug anyway.  Let's see what happens.

Comment: I think the customization variable is actually to get more Emacs-like undo behavior (Emacs doesn't do atomic operations in the same way as vim).

Comment: Here's the new issue: https://bitbucket.org/lyro/evil/issue/444/evils-undo-granularity-is-too-coarse

Answer (score 14):

Since @shosti pointed out that Evil considers deviation from Vim behavior as bugs, I filed a bug and one of the authors of Evil added a new possible value for `evil-want-fine-undo`:

```
(setq evil-want-fine-undo 'fine)
```

With this setting, you get new undo units when moving the cursor in insert mode, but replace operations are undone in one step.  As far as I can tell this is consistent with Vim.  See [here](https://bitbucket.org/lyro/evil/issue/444/evils-undo-granularity-is-too-coarse) for details.

Comment: This solution is not anymore recommended because the `'fine` setting has been deprecated.

Answer (score 7):

According to the variable description (see `C-h v evil-want-fine-undo`) the value `fine` is not supported any more due to inconsistent behaviour.

As I use undo to undo typos or the mentioned setting helped my allot.

```
(setq evil-want-fine-undo t)
```

I had trouble undoing errors in org-table formula editing, since you don't have to leave the insert mode if you want to change to `*Edit Forumlas*` with `C-'`.

Comment: Thanks for the update.  I requested that the issue on Bitbucket is reopened.

Comment: Doesn't work for me using Doom Emacs with 27.2.

Answer (score 2):

Setting simultaneously

```
(setq evil-want-fine-undo t)
```

and

```
(advice-add 'undo-auto--last-boundary-amalgamating-number
            :override #'ignore)
```

as suggested in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41560712/10464013), gives very fine granularity, that is, undoing each character entered in insert mode one by one.

Comment: Neither of these options work for me using Doom Emacs with 27.2.

`(setq evil-want-fine-undo t)` does break up the large undo cadence, but neither make it single keystroke like I want.

Comment: Weird. I am using emacs 28.0.91 and they do precisely that.To which files have you added those lines? I suggest adding the `(advice ...)` one to `.doom.d/config.el` and the `(advice-add ...)` one to `.doom.d/custom.el` through the Custom mechanism [SPC h v, select `evil-want-fine-undo`, follow the Customize link, set the variable to `t` (or `yes`, maybe) and then `apply and save`]. Report if it works.

Comment: I'd just like to stress that my _and_ in the answer is conjunctive. For the behaviour to take effect I've had to add both settings, none of them alone gave me the wanted behaviour.

Comment: I only just learned about `s-z`.  I was using `u` like the incorrect docs said. 
 https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/70834/doom-emacs-single-keystroke-undo/70835#comment114088_70835

Comment: Nice that you found a solution. (Even if I don't understand what you mean by s-z.) I undo things using `u`, btw.