# Doom Emacs single keystroke undo

Tags: doom, undo

How can I have single keystroke undo using Doom Emacs with Emacs 27.2?  I have already tried multiple suggestions on this site, so far none work.  Perhaps Doom Emacs is the problem, or maybe it's that I'm using Emacs 27.2.  Is there a new solution someone can share?

Comment: Adding a link to one of the related threads:  https://emacs.stackexchange.com/q/47341/2287

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is unknown why the O.P. is experiencing problems.  The following method of installation and usage of a prior answer in a related thread appears to work correctly without any issues.

**STEP #1**:  Install a fresh version of Doom.  In my case, I renamed the existing `~/.emacs.d` to preserve the contents and to enable `git` to create a new `~/.emacs.d` in which to install Doom. In a terminal, run the command:

`git clone --depth 1 https://github.com/hlissner/doom-emacs ~/.emacs.d`

**STEP #2**:  In the terminal, navigate with `cd` over to `~/.emacs.d/bin` and run the command:

`./doom install`

Be patient while many packages are downloaded and installed.

**STEP #3**:  I chose `y` when presented with the prompt/question:

`Download and install all-the-icon's fonts? (y or n)`

**STEP #4**:  In the terminal, run the command:

`./doom sync`

**STEP #5**:  Open up `~/.emacs.d/init.el`, *navigate to the bottom of the file*, and insert the following snippet from the answer to the related question https://emacs.stackexchange.com/a/47349/2287

```lisp
(when (timerp undo-auto-current-boundary-timer)
  (cancel-timer undo-auto-current-boundary-timer))

(fset 'undo-auto--undoable-change
  (lambda () (add-to-list 'undo-auto--undoably-changed-buffers (current-buffer))))

(fset 'undo-auto-amalgamate 'ignore)
```

Save the file.

**STEP #6**:  Open or restart a recent version of Emacs, e.g., Emacs 27.2.

**STEP #7**:  Open a new buffer.  I am unfamiliar with `vi` and `evil`, and `M-x` seems to be disabled, so I used:  `M-:` to access `eval-expression`.  I typed `(find-file "FOO")`.  I pressed the letter "`i`" to enable `insert-mode` to insert text into the current buffer.  I typed the word:  `Hello`.  I used the keyboard shortcut to interactively call `undo-fu-only-undo`, which was bound by default on OSX El Capitan to `s-z`.  Emacs undoes one keystroke at a time.

---

**INSTALL NOTES**:  In my case, OSX El Capitan comes with a pre-installed outdated version of Emacs at `/usr/bin/emacs`.  It was necessary to modify the `~/.emacs.d/bin/doom` script to use a current version of Emacs, or perhaps create an alias so that the script calls to `$EMACS` find a recent version.  I also had to devise a method so that the files used to build Doom could find a more recent version of `git`.  Finally, the file `+azerty.el` was uncooperative with the version of `wgrep` that I used when trying to modify the call to `"git"` -- I'm not sure why the file was uncooperative, but I went ahead and deleted the extra `^M` carriage returns and modified the line with `"git"` to use an absolute path.  However, I do not know whether that file is used when building Doom.

Comment: `s-z` was the solution.  All the Doom keybinding docs (what few correct ones there are) I've read up until now said to use `u` for undo.  Thanks!